# Is there an easy way to migrate a Qt 4.8 VS2010 project to a Qt project using xcode on mac?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macos, qt, xcode4

I currently have a VS2010 project that uses the Qt 4.8 framework. We needed to have some native libraries for video on windows and we will develop the same for the mac. We are now migrating the project over to the Mac Os so we can release on that OS also. I am brand new to Mac, last friday being the first time i have even fooled around with one, let alone xcode. Most of my dev experience has been in the Visual Studio world so i am not too familiar with "make" projects.  We do have some pro files but they are more than a year out of date. What is the best way to migrate the projects between the platforms? Any tips or tricks? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to the effort of migrating from Windows to Mac, I'd definitely recommend using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).

It has many advantages over using hard-coded project files/makefiles.  This answer points to some [CMake tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186110/cmake-tutorial).

There are some [conversion tools](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake#Converters_from_other_buildsystems_to_CMake) which are meant to be able to convert between other buildsystems and CMake, but I have no personal experience of these.

The [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html) sometimes leaves a little to be desired, but the [mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/mailing.html) is usually an excellent place to get help and advice.